# Add menu Item in a group dynamically android navigation menu

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation menu which looks like this -

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:title="Home" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
    android:title="Logout" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/choose_bus"
    android:title="Choose a bus">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/group_select_bus"
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <!--<item-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/menu_option1"-->
                <!--android:title="Bus 1" />-->
            <!--<item-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/menu_option2"-->
                <!--android:title="Bus 2" />-->
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

I want to add **menu_option1** and **menu_option2** dynamically from the activity. I tried this but nothing adding -

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    Menu menu = navView.getMenu();
    MenuItem item1 = menu.getItem(2);
    SubMenu subMenu = item1.getSubMenu();
    subMenu.add("Bus 1");
    subMenu.add("Bus 2");

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this

```
Menu menu = navView.getMenu();
menu.add(R.id.group_select_bus,Menu.NONE,Menu.NONE,Youritem);
```

Comment: Tried this but still the same .

Comment: NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        Menu menu = navView.getMenu();
        menu.add(R.id.group_select_bus,Menu.NONE,Menu.NONE,"BUS-1");

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
MenuItem item = mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2);
item.getSubMenu().add(R.id.group_select_bus, id, Menu.NONE, "Youritem");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to add all items in navigation menu and then change their visibility on specific activity or fragment, like

```
MenuItem item = mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(5);
item.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: I want to add it dynamically

Comment: it will be very difficult for you to add it dynamically with icon

Answer (score 0):

Seems a little late to answer. There is workaround/hack for this. No need to add list. Just add this little line above your code. It surely works.

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.candidates -> {
            binding.navSideView.post {
                navSideView.menu.findItem(R.id.candidateManagement).isVisible = !navSideView.menu.findItem(R.id.candidateManagement).isVisible
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

You need to add navigationview.post Runnable before changing visibility. It will update the menu. It works with group too. :)